# Idiomatic destructuring of enums in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm wondering the best way to handle destructuring enums. I use enums for polymorphism a lot. I know I could use traits and dynamic dispatch, but I'd like to avoid that overhead unless there's a real benefit. I'm not worried about the performance hit, it's more about needing to downcast. But still, I'm open to that if it's more readable, less verbose, etc.

```rust
enum Thing {
    A { foo: i32, bar: bool },
    B { foo: i32, baz: f32, },
}

impl Thing {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        use Thing::*;
        match self {
            A { foo, .. } => *foo,
            B { foo, .. } => *foo,
        }
    }

    fn bar(&self) -> Result<bool, String> {
        use Thing::*;
        match self {
            A { bar, .. } => Ok(*bar),
            B { .. } => Err(String::from("expected A")),
        }
    }

    fn baz(&self) -> f32 {
        use Thing::*;
        match self {
            A { .. } => unimplemented!("expected B"),
            B { baz, .. } => *baz,
        }
    }
}

fn func() {
    ...

    let x = thing.baz();

    ...
}
```

Is this idiomatic? Should I be using traits instead?

Comment: Other than using `A { foo, .. } | B { foo, .. } => *foo` in `foo()` (all bindings of `foo` have the same type, so you can use one match arm), this seems fine

Comment: It's very difficult to say without a concrete example. Are A and B actualy variants of Thing or do they just share behaviour? Traits are there for shared behaviour, enums are there for structure. Also, what if  you have non-shared behaviour, specific to one of the variants? This is already a problem in your example. You can't implement methods on struct variants of your enum, since they're not actually stucts. What if you have very broad behaviour that many types in your program need to implement? Are you gonna make one big enum with all the types in it? So scalability is a concern as well

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should probably be returning `Option`s for `.bar()` and `.baz()`. Perhaps your actual code it makes sense, but in general it'd be the caller that'd want to dictate if a missing value should error (via `.ok_or()`), or panic (via `.unwrap()` or `.expect()`), or simply do something else.

Comment: @kartonrealista thanks. Scalability is a concern. Also, I feel like I'm abusing the struct variant, because, as you say, they're not actually structs. I can provide a simplified concrete example if it's useful. Basically, I'm implementing an AST. The nodes can either be expressions or statements. In order to have a heterogeneous collection, I'm using an enum. To further complicate things, only the expressions variants have types. So if you call node.ty() on a statement, it's an unrecoverable error. That's what I was trying to capture above.

Comment: @cdhowie I didn't know about Code Review! I'll use that in the future.

Comment: I agree with @kartonrealista that this is hard to say without context. The code example you show seems fine. Whether the code you show is suitable for your problem is unclear and requires more context. In general, enums are awesome for polymorphism. Look at other crates' code, like [`Value`](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/5b441a2881da9fd7d08186328849856dda001ad4/src/value/mod.rs#L115) from `serde_json`, which uses the exact principle a lot.